# Rails, edit action does not populate the form correctly with many instances of the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm new to Rails and I'm doing my first project. Also, English is not my native language so bear with me, please.

The problem I'm having is that I have a form with multiple instances of the same model, the data is being created correctly but when I try to edit it the form is populated in the wrong way.

I'm making an app to check if everything goes according to the rules.
The items to be checked are in a nested association Chapters->Subchapters->Checks

Every time the checks are submitted a CheckRound is created and the information of every check is stored separately in CheckResults.

CheckRounds

```
has_many :check_results, inverse_of: :check_round, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :check_results, reject_if: proc { |att| att['observation'].blank? }
```

CheckResults

```
belongs_to :check_round, optional: true, inverse_of: :check_results
belongs_to :check
```

Chapters

```
has_many :subchapters
```

Subchapters

```
belongs_to: chapter
has_many: checks
```

Checks

```
belongs_to :subchapter
has_many :check_results
```

The form displays all the Chapters and the nested Subchapters and Checks.
Every Check displays its name and has a text_area as an input.

The user can fill none or many Checks.

```
<%= form_for(@check_round, :url => {:action => 'update', :client_id => @client.id, :project_id => @project.id}) do |f| %>
  <% @chapters.each do |chapter| %>
    <%= chapter.name %>
    <% chapter.subchapters.each do |subchapter| %>
      <%= subchapter.name %>
      <% subchapter.checks.each do |check| %>
         <%= f.fields_for :check_results do |result| %>
            <%= check.name %>
            <%= result.hidden_field(:check_id, :value => check.id) %>
            <%= result.text_area(:observation, rows: 4, :id =>'obs' + check.id.to_s) %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The controller is

```
def edit
  @check_round = CheckRound.includes(:check_results).find(params[:id])
  @chapters = Chapter.includes(subchapters: :checks).where("segment_id = ?", @project.segment_id).sorted
end
```

If for example, I submit that `check.id = 3` has the `observation = "bad"` when I go to edit every check has "bad" in its observation regardless of its id.

I want to know how can I show in edit all the checks with a blank observation but the ones that were created.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Can you show the logs upon create is triggered?

Comment: INSERT INTO `check_rounds` (`project_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (31, '2017-10-06 19:05:14', '2017-10-06 19:05:14')
INSERT INTO `check_results` (`check_round_id`, `check_id`, `correct`, `observation`, `risk`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (179, 1, 'No', 'asdfadfa', 'Medio', '2017-10-06 19:05:14', '2017-10-06 19:05:14')
  INSERT INTO `check_results` (`check_round_id`, `check_id`, `correct`, `observation`, `risk`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (179, 15, 'No', 'asdfasdfas', 'Bajo', '2017-10-06 19:05:14', '2017-10-06 19:05:14')

Comment: Thats how the data is saved if I fill 2 checks in the same check_round. One check_round and then one check_result for each check filled.

Comment: @leogar07 did any answer worked for you? If so, upvote or accept.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution i've promised.

Sinds you have already defined that check results with blank observations had to be rejected and there will to much logic involved in your erb for its own sake, i would put it all in an helper method so your erb will be cleaner. Something like this:

```
#helpers/check_rounds_helper.rb

def edit_or_instantiate_nested_check_results(f, check_round, check, new_check_result)
  if check.check_results
    f.fields_for :check_results, check_round.check_results.where(check_id: check.id) do |result|
      result.hidden_field(:check_id, :value => check.id)
      result.text_area(:observation, rows: 4, :id =>'obs' + check.id.to_s)
    end #end for the already present check results
    # if u want to add a new check result event if the check is populated
    f.fields_for :check_results, new_check_result do |new|
      new.hidden_field(:check_id, :value => check.id)
      new.text_area(:observation, rows: 4, :id =>'obs' + check.id.to_s)
    end #end for the new check result
  else #if there is no existing check result nest a form for a new one
    f.fields_for :check_results, new_check_result do |new|
      new.hidden_field(:check_id, :value => check.id)
      new.text_area(:observation, rows: 4, :id =>'obs' + check.id.to_s)
    end #end for the new check result
  end #end if statement
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= form_for(@check_round, :url => {:action => 'update', :client_id => @client.id, :project_id => @project.id}) do |f| %>
  <% @chapters.each do |chapter| %>
    <%= chapter.name %>
    <% chapter.subchapters.each do |subchapter| %>
      <%= subchapter.name %>
      <% subchapter.checks.each do |check| %>
         <%= check.name %>
         <% new_check_result = CheckResult.new(check_round_id: @check_round.id, check_id = check.id) %>
         <%= edit_or_instantiate_nested_check_results(f, @check_round, check, new_check_result) %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And that shoud be it ;). Let me know if it did the trick :D!

KR,

Comment: Hi Patrick! More than a year later I came back, sorry! Your solution worked great I just had to tweak one line of code for it to function:
if check.check_results
changed to
if check.check_results.exists?(check_id: check.id)

Thanks man, you really helped me out. Sorry to vanish like that. Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, From what i see 2 things that needs to fixed.

1st, your `f.fields_for :check_results do |result|`
needs an extra parameter to specify which check_results it exactly has to modify... somethings like this:

`f.fields_for :check_results, @check_round.check_results.where(check_id: check.id) do |result|`
in the exact same place so the `check` variable is specify the right way.

2de, you need to permit your nested parameters in your controller so they can be saved when u submit. Normally you should see a method called `check_round_params` in your check_round controller.
this one have to like this for everything to work:

```
  def check_round_params
   params.require(:check_round_params).permit(
   /*your needed params*/, 
   check_results_attributes: [:id, :check_id, :observation, /*all your nested params*/]
   )
  end
```

In short, your `update` and your `create` actions work according to those permitted params, so you need define them there. `check_results_attributes:` is the way that rails understands those params are for nested models.

Here is some documentation you might find interesting:[Nested attributes example](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I did not put it here but I already had the nested params. Your solution only displays the checks that had check_results. I was hoping to get ALL the checks but that the fields where only populated for the ones that had check_results, the rest should be blank. Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok I get where u want to go now... I'll edit my answer later today. In short what I would do  is a if check_result statement. If check.check_result then modify the existing ones, if false initialize a local variable new_result = CheckResult.new... It will be clearer later today xD. U should edit your question too so we know you have your nested params the right way.

Comment: I've tried your solution to my problem and got a :"undefined method `where' for #<Usuario:0x000000000d7c91d0>". Usuario is the equivalent of check_results for this problem.

Comment: @GiovanniDiToro sorry for the late answer... did you found a solution to your problem? You was probably using the 'where' method on a instance I guess...

Answer (score 2):

I believe it works like you want with this (code with some simplifications):

Check

```
class Check < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subchapter
  has_many :check_results

  def check_results_for_form check_round_id
    results = check_results.where(check_round_id: check_round_id)
    results.any? ? results : check_results.build
  end
end
```

CheckRoundsController

```
def edit
  @check_round = CheckRound.find(params[:id])
  @chapters = Chapter.includes(subchapters: :checks).all
end
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@check_round, :url => {:action => 'update'}) do |f| %>
  <ul>
    <% @chapters.each do |chapter| %>
      <li>
        <%= chapter.name %>
        chapter
        <ul>
          <% chapter.subchapters.each do |subchapter| %>
            <li>
              <%= subchapter.name %>
              subchapter
              <ul>
                <% subchapter.checks.each do |check| %>
                  <li>
                  <%= check.name %>
                  check
                  <br>
                  <%= f.fields_for :check_results, check.check_results_for_form(@check_round.id) do |result| %>
                    <%= result.hidden_field(:check_id, :value => check.id) %>
                    <%= result.text_area(:observation, rows: 4, :id =>'obs' + check.id.to_s) %>
                  <% end %>
                  </li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <ul>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are repeating the display of the form fields for `check_results`. Look at line 7 of your view code:

```
<%= f.fields_for :check_results do |result| %>
```

This is displaying the fields for each check result on `f.object` (which is `@check_round`). However, this code gets repeated for each `check` in `subchapter`. That surrounding block gets repeated for each `subchapter` in `chapter`, and the block surrounding that gets repeated for each `chapter` in `@chapters`.

When the form is submitted, the params for `check_results` all have the same names, they are not distinguished by chapter, subchapter, or check. As a result, the only value that gets saved for `observation` is the last one submitted.

I think a solution for your case would be to only show the check_result form fields associated with the current check in the loop. One way to do that is to put a conditional in the loop starting on line 7 of your view code:

```
<%= f.fields_for :check_results do |result| %>
  <% if result.object.check == check %>
    <%= result.hidden_field(:check_id, :value => check.id) %>
      <%= result.text_area(:observation, rows: 4, :id =>'obs' + check.id.to_s) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You could also just loop through the check_results independently of the loops for checks, subchapters, and chapters, but I'm assuming that you want to keep that order and context for the UI.